# How to clear failed test messages?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

After running a test that fails, there's lots of red and messages everywhere. How do you clear all of that out? A clean doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah... It happens a lot with Xcode. I have this problem with building errors too. It only goes away after you change the file they're in.

Comment: @BrunoPinheiro: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Looks like closing/opening Xcode resolves it but kinda overkill.

Comment: This problem bothers me a lot! I can get rid of a single message, changing the line which throws the error. But, this is not practical. Change each line of all failing tests.

Comment: @4thSpace Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as per TDD when a test has failed you have entered the red phase and until you don't fix the failed test(s) and enter the green phase, you cannot just ignore the failed tests by cleaning &/or rebuilding the project.

The only "red" that will go are compiler errors. Not failed test errors.

Just wanted to put it out there that this is not a bug or stupid Xcode behavior. It's just following the true TDD ideology.

### But...

If you really want to clear the "red" statements then comment the test/s or the whole file contents and uncomment it.
This will clear the fail messages but the diamonds will still have the red cross mark.

Cleaning the build will not work, atleast not now until Apple considers breaking out of the TDD ideology is worth their while.
Maybe you can request Apple to provide a solution.